# Recreating Partitions

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, lubuntu

I was experimenting with partitions and now have a system that will not boot.  I can boot on a USB but when I go to load a live version of Lubuntu, I get an error saying it can not write to the partition.  I have looked on line about setting up partitions but am not making progress, probably not understanding.  I do not care about what is on the hard drive.  I would just like to erase and load Lubuntu.  Is there some simple software that I can use to create acceptable partitions that will allow me to erase and load Lubuntu?

Comment: You've not provided any release details for Lubuntu.  Lubuntu provides the *KDE Partition Manager* which can be used to setup drives or partitions on drives, the [manual link for 22.10 is found here](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.6/kde_partitionmanager.html) though do note I've encountered some partition schemes that the *KDE Partition Manager* has trouble with, and using `gparted` (which needs to be installed) is easier.   If you're not using 22.10, the manual link is incorrect, but you didn't provide release details.

Comment: For help with any error messages etc. you experience, eg. your "*I get an error saying it can not write to the partition*" you'll need to be specific with details, ie. what release you're using (it matters esp. if trying to setup partitions during install, as the newer `calamares` releases are better than earlier, and it's release details that tell us what you're using), and the exact error message you get.  My prior comment is *generic* as I don't have specifics that allow me to be more specific.  (in 99% of cases; *KDE Partition Manager* is equal to `gparted`, but there is still that 1%)

Comment: Delete all partitions and create partition table anew, and then new partitions.

Comment: FYI:   If you get a partition error (either in `calamares` the installer, or *KDE Partition Manager* before starting the installation) I'd recommend rebooting the system and trying again. Lubuntu have documented this issue in most recent release notes where you'll be directed to this page (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/calamares-rare-failure-to-create-partition-mkfs-errors/2774).  This issue can occur with Kubuntu (using `ubiquity` & KDE-Qt5 skin) but is more likely with Lubuntu (`calamares`) or Ubuntu Studio (`calamares`).  Failure to reboot can result in more partitioning problems.

Comment: Have you validated the health of your drive (ie. checked it's SMART stats; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: I'm running  the live version of 22.04.  The error when trying to install is "Installation Failed, The installer failed to create a partition table on data.  Details: Create a new partition table (type:gpt) on '/dev/data'".  The system has KDE Partition and I loaded Gparted before.  This is a converted Chromebook with 16GB of memory.  KDE shows /dev/mmcblko with 14.7 GB, teh USB, /dev/zram0 with 941 MB and /dev/data with 14.41 GB.  Numbers don't add up.

Comment: I probably created /dev/data in response to the failure message.  I have looked at the documentation but find it confusing because there are so many ways to partition.  I was hoping the may be a simple brainless solution solution like an iso or app that would simply put in a acceptable partitions that I could then load a new OS over.  There is likely something I'm not understanding about partitions.  This was a self induced problem that started after I was changing partitions.

Comment: This is what GParted looks like https://ibb.co/3RTVBQL

Comment: I don't see any error that says '*can not write to partitions*', in fact you have 0 operations pending on the screen you provided. I don't *currently* understand what you're trying do, thus cannot help sorry.  I'm pretty familiar with Lubuntu tools (*being a Lubuntu team member*), so I'll suggest reading the Lubuntu discourse thread I provided; and ensure you're using 22.04.1 as it has a later/better version of `calamares` than 22.04 & earlier releases had.  Please add additional details to your question, comments aren't easy to read.  (*comments are intended from readers to original poster*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

You can repartition the hard drive using the  KDE Partition Manager application which is built-in on the live USB as any format including the default ext4 format. That's all you need to do, and the Lubuntu live USB installer will do the rest after you start the Lubuntu installation process.

- [The KDE Partition Manager Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/partitionmanager/partitionmanager/partitionmanager.pdf)

Comment: Are you saying to just create one big partition with ext4 format.  does the name matter?

Comment: If your Lubuntu installation needs a 500MB FAT32 EFI System Partition for the GRUB bootloader, the Lubuntu installation will automatically create one. The rest of the Lubuntu installation is all installed on a single ext4 partition by default including the swap file, so there is no need to create a separate swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the KDE partition manager to create efi, root and home partitions.  The manager was not very intuitive for me but it worked out.  I was then able to install Lubuntu.  The preinstall partition looked like this. https://ibb.co/60vBHnF

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your issue, but 10 G is way too small for a root partition. And 3 G is really, really too small for /home. Unless this is some kind of pen-drive install.

Comment: I don't know the specs of your machine, but ensure you have an appropriate size of swap (esp. if RAM on device is limited; <8GB, or you're using high resources apps like web browsers or worse).  I feel don't separate /home & / by choice but *swapfile* will go on /, and if you add apps to your system you'll need space on / for them.  Your own needs will dictate what's best for you too (inc. what you have available). Lubuntu's *swap* FAQ can be found [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-faq/2591)

Comment: Perhaps rather than write your own answer you could accept the answer that karel has given you? https://askubuntu.com/a/1450299/57576

Comment: This is a small chromebook with 16GB.  I am totally inexperienced with partitioning tables and was just looking for some type that would allow Lubuntu to install.  I was missing a target so made a guess .  The one created did allow Lubuntu to load.  The installation changed the partitioning and oddly there is no swap.  I thought that was part of the install.  Post install table is here.  https://ibb.co/LRR8vN2  Perhaps my message was a comment and not an answer.